# django-background-tasks management command not running on AWS elasticbeanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Greetings fellow programmers,
I am currently using django-background-tasks(https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
to run some background tasks on AWS elasticbeanstalk. I initially use this command in the main .config container commands but I get timeout error in deployment because this management command will never finish(it continues to run on).
Now, I am trying using the approach suggested for running cron job on elasticbeanstalk(https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/). Please take a look at my code, it is not running the command. what is wrong pls? I just need the command **python manage.py process_tasks** to keep running on. This is working properly on my local machine since i can easily open another terminal to fire up the **python manage.py process_tasks** command

```
    files:
    "/etc/cron.d/process_tasks_cron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            * * * * * root /usr/local/bin/99_process_tasks.sh

    "/usr/local/bin/99_process_tasks.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            date > /tmp/date
            # Your actual script content
            source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate
            python manage.py process_tasks
            

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
```

Answer (score 1):

this a working version of the code. thanks and hope it helps someone out there.

```
files:
        "/etc/cron.d/cron_process":
            mode: "000644"
            owner: root
            group: root
            content: |
                * * * * * root /usr/local/bin/task_process.sh
    
        "/usr/local/bin/task_process.sh":
            mode: "000755"
            owner: root
            group: root
            content: |
                #!/bin/bash
                exec &>> /tmp/cron_capture_log.txt
                date > /tmp/date
                source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate
                cd /var/app/current
                python manage.py process_tasks
               
    
    commands:
        remove_old_cron:
            command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/cron_process.bak"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a very simple Procfile at the root directory of your project:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 --workers=1 --threads=5 your_proj_name.wsgi:application
tasks: python3 manage.py process_tasks
```

This will make the EC2 instances spawn an additional process running the process_tasks management command, apart from the gunicorn server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).